# Properties won't get serialized into the .designer.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serialization, designer

In VS2010, control properties won't get serialized despite the ShouldSerializeFoo method, with the DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible/Content as well.

Here's the code:

```
class Class1 : UserControl {
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public string Foo {
        get; set;
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() {
        return true;
    }
    public Class1() {
        Foo = "dupa";
    }
}
```

However, the designer doesn't generate anything for this property:

```
        // 
        // class11
        // 
        this.class11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(224, 262);
        this.class11.Name = "class11";
        this.class11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.class11.TabIndex = 2;
        this.class11.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.class11_Load);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mixing serialization schemes. The designer serialization (which is what `DesignerSerializationVisibility` is for) has nothing to do with the instance serialization mechanism (which is what `ShouldSerializeXXX` functions, among many other things, deal with).

`DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` doesn't make much sense for a `string` (or any other immutable type). The designer can view a property's serialization as three types:

- None - it never serializes anything about the property
- Visible - it will serialize the actual value of the property
- Content - it will serialize *the property values of the value of the property*.

By default, a property is considered `Visible`. I realize that my definition of `Content` might be a little confusing. What I mean by that is like this:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public class SomeOptions
    {
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public SomeOptions Options { get; private set; }

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when this class is serialized by the designer, it will look something like this:

```
// myControl1
this.myControl1.Foo = "value";
this.myControl1.Options.Option1 = "option1";
this.myControl1.Options.Option2 = "option2";
```

This should hopefully make more sense; marking a property as `Content` signifies that, rather than serializing the *actual value* of the property (in this case, it would be an instance of `SomeOptions`), it should serialize the property values of that value instead.

So, back to your question, that's why you don't want `Content` for a `string` property. Because `string`s are immutable, there's nothing for the designer to serialize. Either mark it as `Visible` or leave the attribute off entirely (since that's the default).

While it's possible to provide custom direction to the designer as to whether or not you want to serialize a particular property, it's a pretty involved (and nasty) process. The *easy* way, though, is to use the `DefaultValue` attribute on the property. If whether or not the property should be serialized can be determined by comparing its value to a constant (in other words, it's not dependent upon anything else at runtime, like the value of another property), you can decorate the property like this:

```
[DefaultValue("foo")]
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

If the designer then sees that the value of `Foo` is equal to `"foo"`, then it won't serialize the property at all.

Comment: Thanks. The problem actually lied in the designer caching things - cleaning the solution, removing all serializable controls, saving, then restarting VS made it work.

Comment: Adam, would you mind taking a crack at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549351/how-to-persist-design-time-property-changes-that-were-made-programmatically#comment18558472_13549351.  Thanks!