# How to persist design time property changes that were made programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that I added an `Id` string property to.

When the control is placed on a form, I want the constructor to set this to `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`, but only if it hasn't been set before.

When I manually edit this property from the designer, it adds a line of code to the `Designer.cs` file.  How can I do that programmatically?
Specifically, how to do it from within the custom control?

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to achieve exactly? Multiple instances of the control on one form, all with the same value for `Id`? A static property would do that. Set to `null` in the definition, and then check if it's `null` in the constructor.

Comment: No, I want each control to have its own unique value.  I could manually enter a value each time I add the control to a form, but I just wanted to make it automatic so I don't have to.

Comment: The idea is that I'm serializing some info about the control and the next time the program starts it needs to find that info so it needs to retain the Guid.  But I'd just like to make it to where I don't have to instruct other developers to set the Id property to a unique value when they use the control.

Comment: Put the code into your custom controls constructor.

Comment: @ChrisF  That's where it is.  But it doesn't get persisted so each time I close and reopen the form designer it generates a new value.  How to make it serialize that value to the Designer.cs the way it would had I manually edited it in the designer is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Can't the constructor check for the persisted data? (I'm just throwing suggestions out here!)

Comment: Yes, it checks to see if the value is null or an empty string and sets it to a new guid if so.  But when the form is closed, that property change is not persisted to the Designer.cs file so the next time you open the form it's blank again.

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with the designer.cs file? It doesn't exist at runtime. That's why you use Properties.Settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created sample usercontrol that fits your requrements. In this case is "MyLabel" that inherits from Label.

First create separate library that holds MyLabel class and here is the code for this class:

```
public class MyLabel: Label
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        if (this.DesignMode && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ID))
        {
            this.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        this.Text = this.ID;
    }
}
```

As you see my control has ID property that is populated if control is in design mode and no value has been set yet. Checking design mode is important so value will not change if you reopen the project.

Override for OnPaint event is there just to see actual ID value in real time it's not required.

Comment: This doesn't persist the ID **between** executions of the program.

Comment: @ChrisF I can't agree with you. I have tested this between several executions of the program and ID value is persistant (default and custom seted). Did you place MyLabel in seperate library?

Comment: Where does it persist the GUID to?

Comment: Guid is placed in designer file and then compiled into exe/dll.

Comment: I won't have a chance to try this until tomorrow, but this is very similar to what I tried initially.  I am suspecting that you may have left the designer window open while you started and restarted the application to test.  But if you close the designer window and then reopen it the value will probably be different.  I would love nothing more than to be wrong about that though.  I'll let you know tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I had a minute to test it just now and unfortunately no go.  Rather than running the application to test, just close and reopen the designer form and look at the property from there.

Comment: Please make sure that MyLabel class is not inside your app. Place it inside separete dll and add reference inside win app. I have done several tests and ID state was preserved. Test included: reloding project, restarting vs and several executions of the exe program. In all cases ID value was preserved.

Comment: Okay, my apologies.  It just dawned on me that I was reusing the same control each time I made changes rather than removing it from the form and readding it.  Once I did that your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @GregorPrimar There is one thing that still puzzles me.  It only serializes the property when the control is initially placed on the form.  If I clear the Id value then it will populate it with a new value each time the designer is reopened as it doesn't get serialized then.  I'd be curious to know why that is if you have any idea, but either way this is perfect for what I'm trying to do so thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can change condition where ID is validated against null or empty string and add another control property that will act as flag (something like IdWasSet). In the first OnCreateControl just set IdWasSet=true. On any other just skip ID set if IdWasSet==true so control will not set new Guid to ID if empty.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you need is `Properties.Settings`. See [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can set these to default values during design, or load and save at runtime.
Example: with the designer, create a new user scoped `string[]` named IDs. Then in your constructor, something like this

```
string ID = "";
if (Properties.Settings.Default.IDs!=null && Properties.Settings.Default.IDs.Length>0) {
   ID = Properties.Settings.Default.IDs[0];
}
else {
   ID = "random";
   Properties.Settings.Default.IDs = new string[1];
   Properties.Settings.Default.IDs[0] = ID;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

This will use the first element of the stored array if there is one, or it will create a new string if there isn't, and persist it (so it will be read from the settings next time you run the program).

Comment: Application level settings can't be changed programmatically.  User level settings can be, but when another developer grabs the code from source control the user settings aren't going to be included and then it's going to generate a new value for him.  I need the value to remain the same for everyone forever after it gets set the first time.

Comment: Also, how would I connect a setting to a particular control?  I think that just pushes the issue back one step unless I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I added an example of how to use those user scope settings.

Comment: (i.e. If I have 10 different controls that save a setting, what am I going to use to identify the settings?  It seems to me I'd need to do exactly what already trying to do just to accomplish that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you just wanted to persist the settings per computer. But the values should be the same, no matter where the program runs? Then how about creating, say, 100 new GUIDs now and just store those hardcoded in the source?

Comment: When a developer adds this control to a form, he would still have to manually assign one of those guids which is what I'm trying to avoid.  In vb6 there was a propbag that persisted property info and it worked the same in design or runtime, but in .Net it writes code to the designer when you change a property in the designer... but not if you change the property from code during design time.  I need a way to edit a property programmatically during design and have it persisted.