# ChildForm cannot change the properties of the BaseForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Now I have to create a form using custom control box, because of job request.
I have created a simple form class as BaseForm, done with the basic custom control box.
In order to control the `Visible` property of the Maximize and Minimize buttons, I re-write the original properties `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` with the keyword 'new' to hide them.
Then I create two new properties to control the visiblity of the custom buttons.
Code here.

```
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new bool MaximizeBox
    {
        get
        {
            return base.MaximizeBox;
        }
        set
        {
            base.MaximizeBox = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new bool MinimizeBox
    {
        get
        {
            return base.MinimizeBox;
        }
        set
        {
            base.MinimizeBox = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(true)]
    [Description("获取或设置当前窗体是否具有最大化按钮。")]
    public virtual bool MaxBox
    {
        get
        {
            if (btnMaxBox == null)
                return false;
            return btnMaxBox.Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (btnMaxBox != null)
                btnMaxBox.Visible = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(true)]
    [Description("获取或设置当前窗体是否具有最小化按钮。")]
    public virtual bool MinBox
    {
        get
        {
            if (btnMinBox == null)
                return false;
            return btnMinBox.Visible;
        }
        set
        {
            if (btnMinBox != null)
                btnMinBox.Visible = value;
        }
    }
```

And here comes the problems.
These two properties seem work well on designer. And the ChildForm can also be changed if I switch the properties. But they will be re-set if I build the code or directly debug the program. And there's no code about the setting of these two properties in the designer code.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Besides, the DefaultValueAttribute seem not work in designer. 
[image: Properties on disigner]

Comment: Things like `return btnMinBox.Visible;` in something what will be serialized/deserialized doesn't looks nice. Instead you have to use normal full properties and buttons have to synchronize their value. You have to show more code (with buttons, with constructors, etc.) if you want to get help with your solution. See [mcve].

Comment: @Sinatr No, the question is fine.  No more information is required. This problem is completely reproducible if you create a Form1 with the two Buttons mentioned in the code and a Form2 (inheriting from Form1 as described) and paste this code into Form1.  I think it's actually well described and completely reproducible.

Comment: I think this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323837/property-value-of-base-class-not-saved-by-designer)  Which says you'll need to 1) store the state in a variable and 2)
adjust the button visibility after InitializeComponent method and when the value of your property changes.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to override the base Form property values (maybe changing the access modifier of those Button to `public`, so they get serialized in the derived Forms) - since you have `public virtual bool` there - or you want all your derived Forms to have the same properties values or change them depending on the base Form settings only (so all they all have the same visible/invisible Buttons).

Comment: @Wyck Thank you so much for the answer. It can now save the properties' changing in designer code. And the ```DefaultValueAttribute``` also works.